# How to force a fluid DIV to expand to full available width?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a layout with fixed-width left and right sidebars and a fluid main content area that takes up the available space in between, something like this, all with float:left --

```
#left-sidebar {width: 200px;}
#right-sidebar {width: 300px;}
#main-content {margin-left: 200px; margin-right: 300px}
```

If I stuff #main-content everything works as expected.

But if #main-content has little content, its width collapses and it borks my layout.

I have used a very inelegant hack of adding at the end of #main-content

```
<div>a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a </div>
```

and setting its visibility to hidden.

That way, it will expand to the full available width, but I was hoping for something less hacky.

(Needless to say, something as simple as setting #main-content width, or the width of some element within, to 100% is not the solution.)

Comment: If you can't use width:100%; then your page must be poorly structured or malformed.

Comment: how do you display those 3 divs , inline-block ? float ? other ways ?

Comment: GCyrillus, as mentioned in the Q, all floated left.

Jhawinsss: something is definitely malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 Calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) to set a width of 100% minus the width of the sidebars:

```
/* Assuming 200px for each sidebar */

#main-content {
    width: calc(100% - 400px)
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wDMfF/

Comment: Thanks Andrea. That works. I never knew about calc, although quickly reading up about it, the problem is support (not at all in Android, for example).

Comment: Nowhere you mentioned Android :> Btw you're right, [always refer to this site](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) to know which feature is supported by which browser; I strongly suggest you to use some popular system like Bootstrap to handle things like this for desktop AND mobile responsive / fluid layout... don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: I *am* using bootstrap, but show me where they give you a fixed-fluid-fixed layout option! caniuse is where I looked it up, but modernizr can check for css calc compatibility, and I could use that with a workaround script...  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

have your css like so

```
#left-sidebar {float:left;width: 200px;}
#right-sidebar {float:right;width: 300px;}
#main-content {display:block;overflow:hidden;}
```

then in HTML, this is **very important**, **firstly initialize the sidebars** and only then  the content div afterwards. Also you may consider using a wrapper with a clearfix class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't help. Switching the float on #right-sidebar made no difference. Oddly enough, changing the order of the HTML to declare the sidebars first completely broke the layout, so that even my ugly hack no longer worked.

Comment: i think if you use this solution, you have to switch from `margin` to `padding` for the `#main-content`'s CSS

Comment: @terraling obviously you have other crappy styles that are messing with those elements. Calc is only supported in very few browsers at the moment and it is not a wise choice to use it. The method I showed you is the best, and I suppose only cross-browser method, that works and doesn't include hardcoding values. Very poor choice using calc, time'll show you.

Comment: Yes, crappy indeed. Thanks for your deep insight.

Comment: How do you expect me to give you a deep insight when all you have shown are those 3 lines? I mean that some other styles are interfering with those objects in a way that they are not allowing them to line up properly.